# How to solve this integral equation involving a probability density?

Tags: matlab, integral, optimization

Let $a,c,d,e$ be given real parameters. I would like to solve the equation
$$\int_a^{c+x} \left(d+x-y\right)f(y)dy=e$$for $x$ (using Matlab). $f$ is a density function (for the beginning it can be a normal density). Can anyone point towards the general strategy to solve this and some useful commands? I thought of using `fsolve`, but then I don't know how to set up the function, since $x$ appears as a limit of the integral as well as part of the function under the integral.

---

This has been crossposted at mathworks:
http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/309494-solve-for-parameters-of-an-integral-fsolve